# How to Set Corner Radius in Power BI Custom Theme?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to define a custom theme for my Power BI reports. I have been able to 'show' the border and set the color by importing the theme JSON. I cannot find out how to define the corner `radius` in the custom JSON file. Here is what I've tried:

```
{
  "name": "Radius Theme",
  "tableAccent": "#284861",
    "visualStyles": {
        "*": {
            "*": {
                "border": [{
                    "show": true,
                    "radius": "5D",
                    "color": { "solid": { "color": "#00FF00" } }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to reverse engineer, using the Power BI Desktop editor, I setup one visualization with rounded corners and saved the PBIX. When I crack open the PBIX file and check out the `Layout` contents, I see the following the appears to define the visualization border properties with a radius of '10D', just like I set in the UI.

```
                "border": [
                  {
                    "properties": {
                      "show": {
                        "expr": {
                          "Literal": {
                            "Value": "false"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "radius": {
                        "expr": {
                          "Literal": {
                            "Value": "10D"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "color": {
                         ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes and the "D" from the radius value and it will work.

```
"border": [{
                "show": true,
                "radius": 10,
                "color": { "solid": { "color": "#00FF00" } }
            }],
```